# Mysql column types

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in the table

hours at sea - Would be good to be able to store hours and mins so you could say at sea for 1hr and 20mins and to be able to add up all the hours and minutes easily.

team - this stores IDs from the team table, so you may have ids 1,3,10,23,45,34. Number in team changes often.

So which types would you use for these columns? I cant decide between int, decimal, varchar but want the hours at sea to be able to work out its hours (so 60 mins in an hour), with the team column, just storing a list of ids form another table, but not sure if int can handle commas , or if there is a better way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minutes as int for time out.
A many to many table to get the team.

Comment: Thanks :)
The table is trips, so for each trip we record hours at sea and the team on the boat, from a team of 20 between 2-6 team members per trip.

So the many to many table will be huge, with upto 6 rows for each trip. Im still trying to get my head around a 1 to many or a many to many table!